# Interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(x-2)^n\prod_{i=1}^n(n+i)}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(n+i)}{n^n}\cdot(x-2)^n\right)$$

I am here to ask another part of this power series given above. I am to find the "interval of convergence". I have the radius of convergence, which is $e\over4$

To find the interval of convergence, I need to make sure if it is less or less equal, in other words, I need to make sure if it is convergence at the extreme points:
$$x\in\left(2-\frac{e}4,2+\frac{e}4\right)$$

How can I find the interval of convergence? I mean, I try putting $8+\frac{e}4$ instead of $x$ on the power series given at the top, and check if it is converging. But I don't know how to examine it. How do I examine if it is convergent? Is there a way to shorten the power series that is given?

And I will check $8-\frac{e}4$ after that, too.

Comment: Use `\frac{e}4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By Stirling's formula
$$
\frac{{(n + 1)(n + 2) \cdots (2n)}}{{n^n }} = \frac{{(2n)!}}{{n!n^n }} = \sqrt 2 \left( {\frac{4}{e}} \right)^n \left( {1 +\mathcal{ O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right).
$$

Comment: yeah thank you, just realised it while searching the net.